# using mongdb, ruby and sinatra how can use math and aggregate functions?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra

I have a mongodb collection. Using the ruby driver, the following works:

```
search = 'LONDON'
result = posts.find(:district => search).to_a.to_json
```

and produces the following in the firebug console:

```
[{"_id":"{AB46B6E4-46F7-44F6-8D88-0002C05947BB}","price":"450000","date_sold":"2013-10-23 00:00","post_code":"NW6 2DT","house_type":"F","condition":"N","freehold":"L","house_number":"72","flat_number":"FLAT 3","street":"LOVERIDGE ROAD","town":null,"district":"LONDON","region":"CAMDEN","county":"GREATER LONDON"}]
```

There are 30 records in the collection, when I change to an aggregate function as follows:

```
result = posts.find( { :price => { $gt => 100000 } } ).to_a.to_json
```

I get an empty [ ] in the console. Is this because the data type, in the collection, is not set to integer? If so, how can I change it programatically (i.e. not in the shell)?

Or is the query wrong? I am using the mongodb ruby driver.

All help gratefully received, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so close - your example needs quotes around $gt,
and the value of the price field needs to be integer and not string so that $gt will work as you desire.
Here's a test that verifies this.  Hope that this helps.

test.rb

```
require 'mongo'
require 'json'
require 'test/unit'

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @posts = Mongo::MongoClient.new['test']['posts']
    @docs = JSON.parse <<-EOT
[{"_id":"{AB46B6E4-46F7-44F6-8D88-0002C05947BB}","price":"450000","date_sold":"2013-10-23 00:00","post_code":"NW6 2DT","house_type":"F","condition":"N","freehold":"L","house_number":"72","flat_number":"FLAT 3","street":"LOVERIDGE ROAD","town":null,"district":"LONDON","region":"CAMDEN","county":"GREATER LONDON"}]
    EOT
    @posts.remove
    @posts.insert(@docs)
  end

  test "find examples" do
    result = @posts.find( { :price => { '$gt' => 100000 } } ).to_a
    assert(result.count == 0)
    puts "result from post: #{result.to_json}"

    @docs.each{|doc| doc.delete("_id"); doc["price"] = doc["price"].to_i}
    @posts.insert(@docs)
    result = @posts.find( { :price => { '$gt' => 100000 } } ).to_a
    assert(result.count > 0)
    puts "result after fixes: #{result.to_json}"
  end
end
```

ruby test.rb

```
Loaded suite test
Started
result from post: []
result after fixes: [{"_id":{"$oid": "5355e4c3a3f57661f3000001"},"price":450000,"date_sold":"2013-10-23 00:00","post_code":"NW6 2DT","house_type":"F","condition":"N","freehold":"L","house_number":"72","flat_number":"FLAT 3","street":"LOVERIDGE ROAD","town":null,"district":"LONDON","region":"CAMDEN","county":"GREATER LONDON"}]
.

Finished in 0.00482 seconds.

1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
100% passed

207.47 tests/s, 414.94 assertions/s
```

Comment: You're welcome, and I hope that your applications are zooming ahead.